How to get KUKA arm's inertia and mass for the URDF?
Do you know if there is any way to get inertia and mass of the links of a KUKA robotic arm? Even an approximate value would be very useful. I've tried to assume homogenousity of the links and I've assumed them to be made of cast iron but I get values too exaggerated and wrong.

Visit the manufacturer's web site and explore such technical specifications as they supply for your particular robot arm. It looks like every page has a link for "Chat with an Expert", and there is "KUKA College" offering seminars that might cover what you want. You could use a Contact link to send a engaging description of your project and how the information you seek would help, if you have plenty of time to wait for it to get routed around until an actual engineer responds.
